# Looping through CSV files in a directory and inserting them into Access

Tags: c#, csv, ms-access, directory

I have a directory that contains a large number of CSV files. I want to loop through the directory and insert each file into a specific table based on their file name.

I am able to successfully loop through the files but I am having some trouble inserting the data into the Access database. I believe I am very close though. Any feedback would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
string folderPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Reports");
string folderPath2 = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\Reports\";
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

foreach (var fileInfo in dir.EnumerateFiles("crashes_*.csv"))
{
    OleDbCommand cmdBulk = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO tbl_crashes " +
                    @"SELECT * FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;ACCDB=Yes;Database=" + folderPath2 + "].[" + Directory.GetFiles(folderPath2, "crash*.csv") + "]", MyConn);

    MyConn.Open();
    cmdBulk.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MyConn.Close();
}
```

This is the error that I am receiving:

> Invalid bracketing of name 'System.String['.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop looks like it iterates over a bunch of files returned by `EnumerateFiles`, but then inside the loop you don't actually use the `fileInfo` variable and instead call `Directory.GetFiles` which looks like it would return another *list* of files (or perhaps the same list again).

Comment: @GordThompson How can I use the fileInfo variable to perform an action on each file?

Comment: This piece seems odd...
You are trying to a append an array to a string... this doesn't look right...

`].[" + Directory.GetFiles(folderPath2, "crash*.csv") + "]"`

Comment: @pmeyer Any way I can alter this to insert files with the file name 'crash*.csv'?

Comment: On each iteration of the `foreach` loop, the `fileInfo` variable will be a [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object for each of the files found by [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574(v=vs.110).aspx). So, you should probably be able to use `fileInfo.Name` (instead of `Directory.GetFiles`) to build the SQL command text for each file.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you! That worked perfectly. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I image that you need to do some thing like ].[" + fileInfo.Name + "]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting 101: When "something goes wrong", break the problem down to isolate the cause.

In this case, the error

> Invalid bracketing of name 'System.String['.

is a pretty strong hint that there is something wrong with the CommandText string that we glued together, so let's look at the relevant bits of the string itself.

```cs
string folderpath2 = @"C:\__tmp\";
string str = "stuff [" + folderpath2 + "].[" + Directory.GetFiles(folderpath2, "zzzTest*.csv") + "] more_stuff";
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

produces

```
stuff [C:\__tmp\].[System.String[]] more_stuff
```

so we can see that the string concatenation does an implicit `ToString` on the result of the `GetFiles` method call, returning `"System.String[]"`. That is, `GetFiles` returns *an array of strings* and the implicit `ToString` shows us what the result *is*, not what it *contains*.

So that explains the error: The extra square brackets got the OleDb provider upset.

The solution, however, is to just use the `Name` property of the `FileInfo` object that the `foreach` loop is providing for us

```cs
string folderpath2 = @"C:\__tmp\";
var di = new DirectoryInfo(folderpath2);
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles("zzzTest*.csv"))
{
    string str = "stuff [" + folderpath2 + "].[" + fi.Name + "] more_stuff";
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

producing

```
stuff [C:\__tmp\].[zzzTest1.csv] more_stuff
stuff [C:\__tmp\].[zzzTest2.csv] more_stuff
```

which is more like what we want.